# Node.js and Express static middleware routing views

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

This seems to me like a pretty basic question, but I haven't been able to find an answer.

I'm using express with `ejs` as template engine and the following dir structure:

```
 |-static
 |---css
 |---img
 |---js
 |-views
```

I have static routing defined for `static` folder:

```
app.configure(function(){
        app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
        app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
        app.use(express.bodyParser());
        app.use(partials());
        app.use(express.methodOverride());
        app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static'));
        app.use(app.router);
        app.enable("jsonp callback");
    });
```

In `Views` folder i keep all of my `ejs` files - one `layout.ejs` and the rest are files with the actual content of the specific page.

I've defined the following routes:

```
app.get('/', function(req,res){
    locals.date = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
    res.render('home.ejs', locals);
});

app.get('/about', function(req,res){
    locals.date = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
    res.render('about.ejs', locals);
});
app.get('/contact', function(req,res){
    locals.date = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
    res.render('contact.ejs', locals);
});
```

which takes `layout.ejs` and renders it with the page together.

Obviously I don't want to add a new route each time I add a new page, I want it to be done automatically.

So I am guessing it should have to do with defining another `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views'));` ? also I don't want the url to show `/about.ejs` but to show `/about`

Can someone please point me in the right direction ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write your own routing logic, for example

```
function customRouter (req, res, next)
{
    var locals = {};
    var controllerName = req.params.controllerName;
    res.render(controllerName + '.ejs', locals);
}

app.get('/:controllerName', customRouter);
```

This is a simple example however it should give you the trick. You can modify it according to your own needs.

Comment: I have a followup question about the method you sugegsted. Trying to access file located in `sample/file` doesn't work, but accessing `file.ejs` works (both files are located in `/views/sample` and `/views` respectively). Do you know why ?

Comment: yes. here's my app.js : http://pastebin.com/a81yBPHC and my server.js: http://pastebin.com/vdsN8rcA . I have edited it like you said, but now that i have added a directory under views : `views/lessons` and i have `lesson01.ejs` there and trying to reach it, i get 404 error.

Comment: You should read the `req.url` and check that there is folder with the same name of your first `uri` component. You can check that with `fs.existsSync(filePath)`. If the directory is exist, then you should check for the new directory by adding second `uri` to your control path. By the way, in this method, you should use `app.get('/*', customRouter);` since you are using your own custom routing.