# Nodejs and express static view routing

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

My question is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13430561/node-js-and-express-static-middleware-routing-views) stackoverflow question.

I have my directory structure as:

```
 |-static
 |---css
 |---img
 |---js
 |-views
 |---login.ejs
 |---pure.html 
 |---dash
 |-----dashboard.ejs
 |-----alsopure.html
```

My configuration:

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static'));
```

I have also defined the routes as:

```
app.get('/login', function(req,res){
    //some locals
    res.render('login.ejs', locals);
});

app.get('/dash', function(req,res){
    locals.date = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
    res.render('dash/dashboard.ejs', locals);
});
```

In the views folder, I keep both my pure static html and my dynamic `ejs` files.

Now, how do I serve the static html from the views directory? Since if I would add the /views folder to serve as a static the user would be able to see my ejs files as well, if they hit the correct url.

Since there are multiple html files, I would not like to add a new route for every new page.

Also, is there any way for me to indicate to my view engine that is a static html and there's no need to 'process' this page?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you move your `HTML` files to a static folder and serve files from there?

Comment: Or, you can add a `public`  folder and make it as static ?

Comment: @CuriousMind since I wanted to keep all view related content within one folder for ease of access and organization.

Comment: @abdulkhodir that is similar to what CuriousMind said and I do not want to keep them separate.

Comment: So, you may need to use [consolidate](https://github.com/tj/consolidate.js) for your view engine. but also, at least it will need to `process` or `function` to serve your html page.

Comment: Take a look at [express](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) documentation. there is a route method like this `app.get(/.*fly$/, function (req, res) {
  res.send('/.*fly$/')
})` . I think you can change `/.*fly$/` with `/.*.html$/` to serve your html files.

Comment: @abdulkhodir thanks, but this would make some pages have an `html` extenstion and some don't. ex: website.com/login & website.com/pure.html which will not look elegant.

Answer (score 0):

So, You can use `nodejs` `fs` and then routes be like :

```
app.get(/.*/, function(req, res, next) {
  var path = __dirname + '/views/' + req.path + '.html';
  if(fs.existsSync(path)) {
    // Consolidate function to load html with path
  } 
  else {
    next();
  }
}
```

Or you can just use it as middleware :

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var path = __dirname + '/views/' + req.path + '.html';
  if(fs.existsSync(path)) {
    // Consolidate function to load html with path
  } 
  else {
    next();
  }
}
```

but i think it will become a bloat for your program :). because for every response it will search for the html file.

Comment: Along a similar line (although I would suggest using a proper middleware), you can check if the requested path has a `.ejs` extension, and refuse to serve it.

Comment: Yeah thanks.  I've just edited the comment @robertklep.